# subprocess.call where is stdout on windows?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I am using `subprocess.call` to run an executable from a python script

works fine under linux, the `stdout` from the executable is printed to the terminal as desired

when running the same `subprocess.call` on windows (7) the command executes successfully but i get no `stdout` to the `cmd` window

my subprocess.call looks like this:

```
call([self.test_dict["exe"],
              "-p",
              self.test_dict["pulse_input"],
              "-l",
              self.test_dict["library_input"], 
              "-c",
              self.test_dict["config"],
              "-r",
              self.test_dict["pulse_output"],
              "-s",
              self.test_dict["stream_output"],
              "-u",
              self.test_dict["library_output"],
              track_output_flag,
              track_output_string,
              socket_output_flag,
              socket_output_string,                 
              "-f",
              self.test_dict["frame_size"], 
              "-d",
              self.test_dict["ddi_enable"],
              self.test_dict["verbose"],
              ])
```

how can i get the executables stdout displayed in the windows cmd window, i.e. how can i get the same behaviour i observe under linux?

I can now see some output using the Popen approach suggested below. my Popen call looks like this:

```
   print(subprocess.Popen([self.test_dict["exe"],
                            "-p",
                            self.test_dict["pulse_input"],
                            "-l",
                            self.test_dict["library_input"], 
                            "-c",
                            self.test_dict["config"],
                            "-r",
                            self.test_dict["pulse_output"],
                            "-s",
                            self.test_dict["stream_output"],
                            "-u",
                            self.test_dict["library_output"],
                            track_output_flag,
                            track_output_string,
                            socket_output_flag,
                            socket_output_string,                 
                            "-f",
                            self.test_dict["frame_size"], 
                            "-d",
                            self.test_dict["ddi_enable"],
                            self.test_dict["verbose"]],
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate())
```

On linux:

> ('    Test Harness - Version 2.2.2\n  \n\nFrame 1 of 5: 1000 of 4032
>   pdws Rx: 0.206, G2: 32.337 (kpps) lib: ddi_n 0 residue: 11 \nFrame 2
>   of 5: 2000 of 4032 pdws Rx: 0.174, G2: 35.396 (kpps) lib: ddi_n 0
>   residue: 18 \nFrame 3 of 5: 3000 of 4032 pdws Rx: 0.197, G2: 31.913
>   (kpps) lib: ddi_n 0 residue: 25 \nFrame 4 of 5: 4000 of 4032 pdws Rx:
>   0.139, G2: 33.908 (kpps) lib: ddi_n 0 residue: 13 \nFrame 5 of 5: 4032 of 4032 pdws Rx: 2.581, G2: 20.164 (kpps) lib: ddi_n 0 residue: 0
>   \nlibrary status: lib.n: 52 lib.ddi_n: 0 lib.orig_n: 52\nelapsed time:
>   0.300253 (s)\n\n', '')

On Windows:

```
('', '')
```

the first bit of the linux output is what i would like to see printed to stdout on windows

i was mistaken that adding `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` was fixing the problem on windows, it wasn't - apologies for the confusion

Comment: Can you redirect stdout with subprocess.PIPE and read from it in Python to confirm that data is actually being sent there? Does the executable print when run on its own?

Comment: the exe definitely outputs to stdout fine when run on its own. i don't follow the 1st bit..

Comment: When you run a command with the `subprocess` module, you can redirect the stdout and stderr streams to in-memory buffers or file-like objects. Then you can read out of the buffers to make sure that there is actually information being sent. Your call would look like the following, placing your command in `cmd_str`

`print(subprocess.Popen(cmd_str, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate())`

Comment: what happens if you replace call with check_call ?

Comment: no difference between using call or check_call on either platform - is the latter supposed to write anything extra to stdout or stderr?

Comment: no but there is a difference in what happens if the return code is non zero, Popen should work on either platform using communicate

Comment: have you piped to stdout and print proc.communicate()

Comment: add the exact subprocess commands you are using, also are you piping stderr?

Comment: try `for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline,""):print line` where `proc = subprocess.Popen....` without the communicate

Comment: Are you sure that the commands under windows write to stdout and do not use low level console output ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta the exe i'm running is one i've written myself, so i know its writing to stdout (i've not heard of low level console output though)

Comment: Could it be a path problem ? Is `self.test_dict["exe"]` a full path executable name (`x:\\path\\name.exe`) ?